# From data to ANOVA

Tags: anova, experiment-design

I did an experiment in which I used electrical stimulations.
The stimulation is defined by 2 parameters, pulse and frequency. I used 3 different frequencies (20, 70, 120) and 4 different pulses (100, 200, 300, 400).

Each pulse/frequency combination was given 3 times in randomized order to the subject.

I have 16 subjects involved in the study.

My null hypothesis is that there is not difference among different combinations.

I cannot find a way to implement it by hand (also using a software would be ok), it looks like an ANOVA with repeated measurements.

Do you have any hints?

Comment: Any information on the nature of the dependend variable? Which software is accessible to you?

Comment: Hi Bernhard,Unfortunately this is all the information that I've got. As a software, I can use SPSS statistics and Matlab.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a 3x4 ANOVA, using as factors '*frequencies*' [levels: 20, 70, 120], and '*pulse*' [levels: 100, 200, 300, 400]. You may want to specify to your software (MatLab is good for this, but also more GUI software like Statistica) that you are using ***repeated measures***; and you may want to specify if you need the ***interaction*** between 'pulse' and 'frequencies'.

First, create a variable 'data' which is a vector containing all the data...it should be long 192 datapoints (192 = 16x3x4).
Then, create three 192 x 1 cell variables which contains, in each row, the specifier of *frequencies* (**label_f**), *pulse* (**label_p**), and *subject* (**label_sub**).

Use anovan to obtain output tables and variables; be sure to specify the correct model -> [1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1; 1 1 0] to have also the interaction frequencies X pulse. Specify also " 'random' , 3" to tell MatLab that **label_sub** is for the repeated measures.

```
[p,table,stats] = anovan( data , {label_f, label_p, label_sub} , 'model' , [1 0 0; 0 1 0; 0 0 1; 1 1 0] , 'random' , 3 )
```

Be sure to check the function 'multcompare', then. For example, it should be useful for you to type something like

```
multcompare(stats,'dimension',[1 2])
```

Simone

Comment: Hi Simone, this definitely helps. Could you guide me through the Matlab code for doing this?

Comment: You should use the function anovan.

Comment: Interactions? Be carefully at only n=16 probands.